# What do you do when there is nothing good to screw in to for a towel rack?

Tags: bathroom, bathroom-fixtures, drywall-anchor

Yes seems easy but happens all the time.    Just bought a house and the previous owner duped us on a towel rack.   Pure mud patches right behind the rack.   Would have to lower it 3-4 inches and might be too low.     Any tricks or easy ways out when you have a bathroom towel rod that can't be secured well?

Comment: [Which type of drywall fastener should I use for a bath-towel bar or hand-towel ring?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/271016/35141)

Comment: Would think drywall anchors will be okay for towel rods, but you know that is not the case.  Find studs, use a 1x4/1x6 to span studs and stain/paint.

Comment: [How can I fix a towel bar pulled from the wall?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/251356/35141)

Comment: [Many more](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Adiy.stackexchange.com+towel+bar+backing&rlz=1)

Comment: Drywall anchors. There's an Amazon product called Bullfix anchors that I like if the anchor doesn't show. Toggle bolts give a nice strong anchor. For towels, not people.